# How to make Accounts not related to Contact available in a picklist (via a Flow in a Community Portal)

Tags: sharing, portal

I have set up a flow in our community (Customer Community Enterprise Edition) to allow users to insert a new record (a lab credential) into a custom object.

The portal is set up so that the user has access to Accounts they are related to. They also have access to the custom object and everything works except for one piece:

The credential they are uploading requires that they select the provider.  The providers are listed as Accounts in our instance with their record type set to "Lab".

The Community User has no relationship with the Lab's Account in our instance, so when they try to select a provider, no Accounts are there.

If I add the user as a Related Contact to the Lab's Account, the Account becomes available in the  picklist (and lookup - I've tried both ways).  Obviously, I don't want to add each portal user as a related contact to every Lab Account.

I added an Account Sharing Rule to share all "Account Record Type: Lab" with "All Customer Portal Users", but that seems to change nothing.

I've spent hours trying to figure this out.  I am not a programmer, so I'm looking for a point and click solution.

Grateful for any ideas.

Comment: What is the license type of community users? The sharing set should have worked!

Comment: Thanks for responding, Mohith.  They are Customer Community user licenses.  I can't understand why it didn't work either, but I gave up this morning and just created a dummy picklist of the Labs for the flow. Then I used the Process Builder to assign the account ID to the actual field of record.  

It's a little hokey, but it's done!

Again, thanks for taking the time to respond. I realize this probably wasn't the right forum for this question.

Comment: @K Weber this forum is perfectly right for this query!! It's a great question. Looks like Sharing Sets would have been better looking at the license type.

Comment: Sharing rules do not work with Customer Community users.  As Mohith suggested, Sharing Set is the only way to do limited sharing for Customer Community, but I don't know if it works for Related Contacts either.